# Debugging istio sidecar injection

Tags: kubernetes, istio, istio-sidecar, sidecar

I've installed istio on an EKS cluster.  What started happening is that for some mysterious reason, istio stops executing sidecar injection on new pods.  I've verified that the namespaces have been properly labels, and that the pods do not have sidecar injection disabled.  I did notice that the mutatingwebhookconfiguration at some point was changed, but honestly I'm not sure how.  I reverted the change in the mutatingwebhookconfiguration, but for some reason istio still does not auto inject sidecars on the labeled namespace.

How can I debug this?  I've tried most of the things in the istio FAQ, but it still doesn't seem to work.  The only thing that seems to fix the issue is running

```
istioctl install -f <install file>
```